# Spring Batch - disable ItemReader cache on processor skip, and process filtered rows again

Tags: spring-batch

I have been using Spring Batch for some time already, and today I tried to enhance my batchs to make them more bullet-proofs. So I enabled .faultTolerant and .skipLimit/.skip, but I didn't enable any retry strategy.

Nearly all my batchs have 1 reader (JpaPagingItemReader to read data from my database), 1 processor, and 1 writer to create XML files. These 3 parts are all in one step, and my chunk size is usually around 50.

I noticed two side effects when a skippable exception occurs, and I would like to know if there is a way to change these default behaviors =>

1. I usually read JPA entities in my reader, send them to my processor where I will change their properties to update my database. But when a skippable exception occurs and the entities are processed again, they become detached entities and they don't match the database anymore because their state was updated in the previous process while the database has been rollbacked. 
   I understand that the results of the reader are cached, and that the documentation says that the result of the ItemReader should stay "idempotent" (not changed). But is there a way to disable the cache of the ItemReader, and to force to load a fresh entity when an element is processed again ? It would suit my use case way more.
2. I noticed that when an element is filtered (the processor returns null), and then a skippable exception occurs, the filtered elements are not processed again after the rollback. Is there a way to change that ?

I searched a lot on stackoverflow, the spring batch documentation and on google before asking this question, but I couldn't find my answer.

Thanks in advance for your precious help, and thanks a lot to the developers of Spring Batch for this great tool !

Comment: `So I enabled .faultTolerant and .skipLimit/.skip, but I didn't enable any retry strategy.`: SkipPolicy and RetryPolicy are different in the context of a fault tolerant step. Have you tried using `.retry/.retryLimit`? `is there a way to disable the cache of the ItemReader`: I think [readerTransactionalQueue](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/SimpleStepBuilder.html#readerIsTransactionalQueue--) is what you are looking for (despite the "queue" in the name). Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Skip suit me better than retry :) but readerIsTransactionalQueue seems to be exactly what I wanted, I will try that, thanks ! And do you have any idea about the second question (filtered elements ignored) ? :)

Comment: You are welcome. I added an answer for both questions with more details. Hope its helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. But is there a way to disable the cache of the ItemReader

[readerTransactionalQueue](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/SimpleStepBuilder.html#readerIsTransactionalQueue--) is what you are looking for (despite the "queue" in the name which does not apply to your case, but still, this is what disables the cache).

> 2. I noticed that when an element is filtered (the processor returns null), and then a skippable exception occurs, the filtered elements are not processed again after the rollback. Is there a way to change that ?

I see no obvious way to change that. This is [how it worked](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/6cca32fde0542f7e16c68a051604e63c8bb4cda5/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java#L276) since the beginning  I think (looking at the last modification date). But this makes sense to me, why would one want to reprocess an item if it was filtered? This item would be re-filtered again anyway, unless the processor is not idempotent which is [not recommended](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#faultTolerant).

Comment: Thanks for the more detailed answer ! I want to reprocess the filtered items, because I still do actions on these items. At the very least I insert a line in my report table to say that the item has been filtered. Sometimes I still write some data in the database, like updating the last viewed date. As I see (and as I implemented my batchs), the reader is to read data, the processor is to manipulate data (including editing DB data), and writer is to generate the output, mostly XML files in my case.

Comment: Of course it makes sense to implement it the way it is and to skip filtered items, but I think that it makes sense too to think that if I enable the faultTolerant, I'm expecting the batch to run exactly like it did before, but without reading the element that generated the error on the first pass. To do that, I need to enable readerTransactionalQueue and I would have needed another flag to enable the processing of filtered items. If you think that my point of view is valid and that such flag can be added to Spring Batch, you would make me the happiest man :-) otherwise I'll see to adapt myself

Comment: There is a similar flag for the processor called [`processorTransactional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/FaultTolerantStepBuilder.html#processorNonTransactional--). Have you tried that?

Comment: By the documentation it doesn't seem to do what I want, because if I disable it (it's enabled by default) Spring Batch will not process again in case of skip. What I need is Spring Batch to process everything again (except the error) :-)

Comment: ok I just wanted to know if you tried that flag or not. Actually spring batch will retry every item of the failed chunk except filtered items (this is how it worked since the beginning as mentioned in the answer), but I understand that this is not what you are looking for.. At least I tried to help by giving some insights about the current state of things.

Comment: Yes and I thank you for your precious time :-) I will see if I can adapt my batchs, or if I can ask a feature request on the project or maybe do a PR !